# Parent-child query returns Aggregate Query Exception

Tags: apex, query, relationships

I am getting all the contacts for the account and wanted to load it in a map
Reference :

```
Map<string, decimal> mapcol = new Map<string, decimal>();
for(Account acc : select id, (select id, name from contacts) from Account WHERE Id IN: trigger.new){
    mapcol.put(acc.id, acc.contacts.size()) ********here it is getting error*****
}
```

Error :

> Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR
>   loopExternal

I know every subquery is calculated as a seperate query.

What will be the workaround for this?
Any suggestions is appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error has suggested, you have to use another for loop inside the outer for loop. So, your code would be:

```
Map<string, decimal> mapcol = new Map<string, decimal>();
for(Account acc : [select id, (select id, name from contacts) from Account WHERE  IN: trigger.new]){
    //This should be removed : mapcol.put(acc.id, acc.contacts.size()) ;
     Integer count=0;
    for (Contact c : acc.Contacts) {
        count++;
    }
    mapcol.put(acc.id, count) ;
    system.debug('---------------------'+mapcol);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But the problem is not with the map collection. Problem is with the subquery. So is there any workaround for forming this query in someother way?.

Comment: Hi Mohammed, thats what I have answered. I agree that the problem is not map collection. You have to use the sub for loop as I have given in the answer. This solution has been provided by Salesforce only. You can see it here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link. Actually this gave me some idea's on subquery. I'll try this solution.